# VS Code AMD Module System

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, amd

I'm working on an Electron application using TypeScript and I'm running into some issues while trying to figure out the module loading system to use. I have been digging through the VS Code code (since many consider it the "poster child" for Electron apps done right) in order to get a better understanding of conventions/the best ways to do certain things, and I've noticed that they are using AMD modules (in the tsconfig.json file under src, the options `"module": "amd"`, `"moduleResolution": "classic"`, and `"baseUrl": "."` are all set) and they seem to be using requirejs-like calls for certain things, such as loading the URL into the BrowserWindow, where they use `require.toUrl('vs/workbench/electron-browser/bootstrap/index.html');` to get the full URL to load.

From my (admittedly limited) understanding, this solves a problem that I am running into where I compile my TypeScript (located in the `src` directory) to an output directory (called `out`) then provide the .js files to Electron to execute, meaning that my paths for things like `mainWindow.loadUrl(__dirname + '/index.html')` suddenly point to `out/index.html` instead of the intended `src/index.html`. However, as I'm searching through the VS code project for any reference to the requirejs module, I can't find anything except a `require.d.ts` file containing this code

```
declare var define: {
    (moduleName: string, dependencies: string[], callback: (...args: any[]) => any): any;
    (moduleName: string, dependencies: string[], definition: any): any;
    (moduleName: string, callback: (...args: any[]) => any): any;
    (moduleName: string, definition: any): any;
    (dependencies: string[], callback: (...args: any[]) => any): any;
    (dependencies: string[], definition: any): any;
};

declare var require: {
    toUrl(path: string): string;
    (moduleName: string): any;
    (dependencies: string[], callback: (...args: any[]) => any, errorback?: (err: any) => void): any;
    config(data: any): any;
    onError: Function;
    __$__nodeRequire<T>(moduleName: string): T;
};
```

I've created a typings file containing this within my project, but I'm getting a `define is not defined` error when running my transpiled JavaScript. My question is: how exactly is VS Code able to use AMD modules with the standard Node `require` module, seemingly without using something like requirejs, and could implementing a similar pattern solve my path problems when running the transpiled JavaScript code from an output directory? Thanks!